# Determine theoretical max connections for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, max-connections

I want to upgrade the ram our MariaDB server `(10.1.25-MariaDB-1~xenial)` to handle more connections.

I have been determining the max connections mostly based on [this article](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/11/error-1040-too-many-connection-increase-max-connections-mysql.html) which suggests to use this formula

(Available_RAM - Global_buffers) / Thread_buffers

Global_buffers it the sum of these variables.

```
key_buffer_size
innodb_buffer_pool_size
innodb_log_buffer_size
innodb_additional_mem_pool
net_buffer_length
```

Thread_buffers is the sum of these variables.

```
sort_buffer_size
myisam_sort_buffer_size
read_buffer_size
join_buffer_size
read_rnd_buffer_size
```

This appears to work and for me it gives approx. **15 connections** as my theoretical max.

When I query `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections'`, which to my understanding gives me the historical `maximum connections` requested, I get **46 connections**.

For background when I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'` I get **151** which I believe is the default setting value.

Is **15 connections** actually my theoretical max and did the additional **31 connections** failed but MySQL registered them?

Is my math wrong or more likely am I missing some variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every formula I have found is wrong in some respect.  Almost every computer I have encountered has "overcommitted" RAM; that is, the formula would say that too much RAM could be used.

Their list is missing two important settings:  `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size`.  The min of those two is what is used for internal temp tables in complex `SELECTs`.  *And there could be multiple uses in a single query!*  I recommend limiting each to 1% of RAM.

Overall...

- Leave most VARIABLES at the defaults.
- The 1% mentioned above
- use InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- Set `key_buffer_size` to just 20M.
- Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM if you have more than 4GB of RAM.  (A lower percentage for tiny machines.)  This is the first thing to reach for if swapping occurs.
- When you find problems (swapping, high cpu, high I/O, etc), ask for help.  It will *usually* be solved by better INDEXing and/or reformulating queries, *not* by tuning.

Ignore the formulas like what your question is posing.

As for "too many connections", there are two main causes *and tuning MySQL/MariaDB is not the cure*.

- The queries are running so slowly that they need help -- tuning *queries* is a solution here.
- The clients are flooding the database.  Some web servers think that they can efficiently run hundreds or thousands of threads.  But, in reality, they stumble over themselves and cause the database to also stumble over itself.  Throttle them.

On this last bullet item, think of a grocery store where so many shoppers are in there that they can't even push their carts to the next aisle, much less ever get finished.

Put another way, if you let too many connections in, throughput stalls (hits some limit) and latency suffers badly.

Things to watch for:

- Swapping means things are tuned too high -- discussed above
- 100% CPU or I/O -- Fine and fix the queries.  For help in finding them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog
- Poor latency (queries taking "too long") -- See the other two items.

Comment: Thank you! Not exactly the answer I wanted but it probably the one I needed to hear.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the default `MAX_CONNECTION` is 151 connections & the MySQL instance has only reached 46 connections as `MAX_USED_CONNECTIONS` ( till now the instance has only 46 concurrent connection ).

For increasing `RAM` according to `max_connection` limit, you can get estimate by filling you instance parameter value on following site, this will get approx `RAM` value which is going to used when your instance hit `MAX_CONNECTION` limit :

https://www.mysqlcalculator.com/

Comment: Thank you for the site, it is helpful. Do you know the math on this?

Comment: Also, do you know how they are determining which variables to use?

Comment: Yet another example of a formula that is not-quite-right.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Rick James [says in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286860/23721), human-initiated database connections may be long-lived but most of the time they tend to remain idle, unnecessarily hogging database server resources. Consider using connection pooling in your application, and your perceived maximum of 15 connections could very well be enough to support the pool without causing waits on the application side.